# Android: How to make a Slider like this in android?

Tags: android, slider

Is there any defined View to have a slider like this??

[image]

Can i keep 2 fingers one each on the bubbles and pinch in/out to decrease/increase the blue line??

or atleast slide 1 bubble at a time??

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/   is what you want!

Intro:

The Android widget class library contains only one "slider" like widget: the SeekBar. SeekBar only supports one thumb control and thus handles only one selectable value. If you need a widget allowing to handle two values (like a minimum and maximum value or a range), this RangeSeekBar widget might suit your needs. It supports controlling minimum and maximum values on a numerical range of the following types: Long, Double, Integer, Float, Short, Byte and BigDecimal.

Comment: I dont think you can pinch with this, but you definetely get the range selector you are looking for.  And then you can always subclass and add your own features.